# Detecting outliers using 95% PI around a natural spline fit

Tags: outliers, splines, prediction-interval

Please see the picture below:
[image]

I wanted to mark the points that are not consistent with their adjacent points as outlier. What I did was to fit a natural spline fit to 1000 observations (the purple line in the picture is the fitted line). I then consider 95% prediction interval and 99% prediction interval around the fit. I consider any point outside of the 99% PI as outlier. If you look at the picture above, you would see that the red dots are the points that were selected as outliers. In particular look at the outliers after x = 150 (x axis). These are very consistent and should have not been selected as outlier. As you noticed the PI interval is very narrow and I think this is because of two things:

1. n = 1000 is large
2. data is highly correlated

Question is how can I take this correlation into account and get a realistic 95% PI? Do I need a time series approach? What is your suggestion?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In my opinion, the issue here is your choice of smoother. The reason your approach breaks down is because the natural spline fit oversmooths the local behavior after the 150th observation where there is a sharp dip followed by a large spike. You could try a smaller smoothing parameter but this may have the effect of overfitting the data in other regions. How much of issue that is will depend upon your exact requirements.

Comment: As I see it, there are four problems, 1) the choice of smoother (a LO(W)ESS smoother seems more suited), 2) the choice of bandwidth, 3) the autocorrelation, and 4) the use of prediction intervals instead of the more appropriate tolerance intervals. I would instead fit a *robust version* of LOESS, and just select reasonable limits by hand. Or *if* the resulting autocorrelation (excluding outliers) has a simple form, e.g. AR(1), take this into account when calculating the standard errors.

Comment: @Sam, my comment is little late and off the topic, but I wanted to know what fitting software did you use to calculate the piece-wise bounds for the fitted spline?

Comment: @nole you can reproduce it with python and tsmoothie: A library for timeseries smoothing and outlier detection in a vectorized way https://github.com/cerlymarco/tsmoothie